# Como importar a biblioteca Chart.js em um arquivo ASP?

Tags: html, asp, chartjs

Estou tentando inserir um gráfico com o Chart.js em uma página ASP (não ASP.NET). Vi alguns tutoriais do próprio Chart.js e encontrei a seguinte instrução:

> You can download the latest version of Chart.js from the GitHub releases.
>
> [...]
>
> Chart.js can be installed via npm or bower.
>
> For npm:
>   `npm install chart.js --save`
>
> [...]
>
> Chart.js can be integrated with plain JavaScript or with different module loaders. The example in below show how to load Chart.js in Script mode.
>   `<script src="path/to/chartjs/dist/Chart.js"></script>`.

Logo, interpretei que em "`src`" preciso colocar o caminho do arquivo Chart.js que eu baixei. Então, colei este arquivo na pasta `Library` do meu projeto. O arquivo em que quero inserir um gráfico é o `grafico_diario.asp`, contido na pasta raiz do projeto. Então, nesse arquivo ASP, coloquei assim:

Porém, o gráfico não aparece quando eu testo no servidor. Vocês podem me dizer se estou importando a biblioteca corretamente?

Comment: coloque a tag script na página asp onde você vai gerar o gráfico, no src coloque o caminho onde esta o arquivo chart.js. mostre o erro que aparece no console do browser para sabermos mais detalhes

Answer (score -1):

Um teste que você poderia fazer é pegar o CDN do chart e incluir dentro das tags `<head></head>` sua página:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.min.js">
</script>
```

E rodar um teste, como esse:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
```

Comment: Como resultado ela ficaria assim:
https://pste.eu/p/cFLG.html